# Render different html depending on index of object in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor, collections

In my meteor project I have a collection called auctions. Using react I wish to render 3 columns of this auctions with unlimited number of rows. To accomplish this I thought it would be possible to send the index of the object but I have no idea how to do this. Another problem is that it shows an error with the html code since I'm not closing the 'div' tag.

This is my App.js:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

            import { Auctions } from '../api/auctions.js';

            import Auction from './Auction.js';

            //App component - represents the whole app
            class App extends Component {
                renderAuctions() {
                    return this.props.auctions.map((auction, index) => (
                        <Auction key={auction._id} auction={auction} index={index} />
                    ));
                }

                render() {
                    return (
                        <div className="container section">
                            <div className="row">
                                {this.renderAuctions()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }

            export default withTracker(() => {
                return {
                    auctions: Auctions.find({}).fetch(),
                };
            })(App);
```

And my Auction.js:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';

            //Task component - resepresnts a single todo item

            export default class Auction extends Component {
                render() {
                    if(index % 3 === 0) {
                        return (
                            </div> /* Shows an erros here because of closing tag*/
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col s4 ">
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="card-image">
                                            <img src="images/logo.png" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-content">
                                            <span className="card-title">
                                                {this.props.auction.auctionName}
                                            </span>
                                            <p>
                                                I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                                                I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-action">
                                            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        );
                    } else {
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <h1>Brincoooo</h1>
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-image">
                                    <img src="images/logo.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <span className="card-title">
                                        {this.props.auction.auctionName}
                                    </span>
                                    <p>
                                        I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                                        I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-action">
                                    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: The Auction component shouldn't need to know it's index. You could split your list of auctions into 3 separate lists in the parent and render them accordingly.

Comment: You mean in the render function inside App class?? @trixn

Comment: Why are you writing </div> just after return ?

Comment: To close the last <div className="row"> @Rahamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you return HTML from a render function it needs to be self contained and have balanced tags. That's the way React works, and why it's giving you an error.

Instead of trying to group 3 auctions at a time, you could think of using flexbox instead. With flexbox you simply render all of your auctions, and it looks after the wrapping automatically for you. Users with wider screens will see more than 3 columns, and users on mobile will see probably one when in portrait mode.

If you want to learn about flexbox, there is a cute tutorial here: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ There are plenty of tutorials around if you don't like that one, such as this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

I'll let you do the work from here